# Create instance using an interface

Tags: typescript, angular

In my Angular 2 TypeScript application, I defined an interface rather than a class to allow optional parameters.

As far as I know, I should somewhere implement the interface by:

> export class myClass implements myInterface { ... }

and then instantiate it via `new(...)`.

I wondered whether this is the right way to do it (in Angular 2) or there is a **simpler / better way**?

Also, **where should I put the implementation**, in the component (.ts) where I use it, where the interface is or where?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can do it that way. You can also just create an object that implements the interface like:

```
interface foo {
    one: number;
    two: string;
}

const bar: foo = { one: 5, two: "hello" };
```

If you want to use a class, you can put it where you want. If it's tightly coupled with the component, you can put it there. Generally though, I want classes to be loosely coupled, so I put them in their own file.

Comment: Another way is: interface foo {
    one?: number;
    two?: string;
}
const bar: foo = {}

Comment: Yet another way is `const bar = { one: 5, two: "hello" } as foo` which is slightly different, as it allows for additional properties beyond the ones defined by the interface. (I'm just noting this here for completeness - the `bar: foo` syntax is the correct thing unless you need additional properties, as it provides the strictest validation.)

Answer (score 71):

I use this way

```
interface IObject{
    first: number;
    second: string;
}
```

then

```
var myObject = {} as IObject
var myListObject = [] as Array<IObject>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution for when I want to instantiate the variable with an interface, but don't know all of the fields at that point in time. It's much cleaner to implement for larger interfaces too.

Comment: This approach defeats the point of type safety: https://zohaib.me/creating-object-based-on-interface-type-in-typescript/

Answer (score 17):

While the accepted answer is good, **beware of solutions like this because they allow you to omit required properties defined in the interface:**

```
const instance1 = {} as MyInterface;
const instance2 = <MyInterface>{};
```

---

Some other robust and compact alternatives include:

1) Instantiate an anonymous class which implements the interface:

```
new class implements MyInterface {
  one = 'Hello';
  two = 'World';
}();
```

2) Alternatively, employ a utility function as follows:

```
export function impl<I>(i: I) { return i; }

impl<MyInterface>({
  one: 'Hello';
  two: 'World';
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it let me instantiate an interface without values.

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following:

```
export interface IMyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: number;
  property3: boolean;
}

export class MyClass implements IMyInterface {
  property1: string = '';
  property2: number = 1;
  property3: boolean = false;
  constructor(){}
}
```

Then to instantiate:

```
let newFromInterface = new MyClass();
```

This is how I do it in my code at least.

Comment: then you don't need to define an interface at all, you are just using your class. Correct syntax is export class MyClass implements IMyInterface

Answer (score 3):

```
interface IOffice {
id: number;
employeeName: string;
phone?: number;
}
export class OfficeComponent {
  officeData: IOffice= <IOffice>{};
  dummyOfficeData: IOffice = {id: 1, employeeName: 'ragnar', phone: 123};
  noPhoneOfficeData: IOffice = {id: 2, employeeName: 'floki'};

constructor(){
  console.log(this.dummyOfficeData);
  console.log(this.dummyOfficeData);
}
}
```

this is better way for me. you can export interface from model file and import in any necessary components.

Answer (score 1):

If implementation is not done properly, you might end up with `{}` which is null but not actual null.

```
 interface foo {
    one: string;
    two: string;
  }
```

if you want to initialize a null interface use `data: foo = null`
if you want to intialize interface with values use `data: <foo>({one:'1',two:'2'})`

Comment: The "data: <foo>({one:'1',two:'2'})" syntax is what I was looking for.