# Cannot set property 'matricule' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm try to make application with Ionic but I get this error `Cannot set property 'matricule' of undefined` 
I don't know what I'm missing in the code

when I want to add data to this table `employeeL` I get this error

I try to make many changes but the problem was the same

the problem that I want to access the HTML element when the table is stay empty
(the problem is on synchronization because I'm calling data from the database  )

please help ,

this is the code HTML :

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>مجموع</th>
      <th>تم</th>
      <th>مثبت</th>
      <th>الاسم و اللقب</th>
      <th>عون الجرد</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of employeeL">
      <td (click)="getuserInfo(item?.matricule)">{{item?.mustBeDone}}</td>
      <td (click)="getuserInfo(item?.matricule)">{{item?.done}}</td>
      <td>
        <ion-checkbox slot="end" checked="{{item?.status}}"></ion-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td (click)="getuserInfo(item?.matricule)">{{item?.fullname}}</td>
      <td (click)="getuserInfo(item?.matricule)">{{item?.matricule}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

here the ts file :

```js
 employeeL:Array<Awinjard> = [];
  inv_agentTab: Array<Inv_agent> = [];
  drafbiesTab: Array<Drafbies> = [];
  nameemployee: string = "";
  inv_agentNombre: number = 0;
  matriculeTable: Array<number> = [];
  nameTable: Array<string> = [];
  validatationTable: Array<number> = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.folder = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    
    
    this.awinjard.getAwinjardMatricule().subscribe(res => {
      this.inv_agentTab = res as Array<Inv_agent>
      this.inv_agentTab.forEach(element => {
        this.matriculeTable[this.inv_agentNombre] = element.AGENT;
        this.validatationTable[this.inv_agentNombre] = element.VLD;
        this.inv_agentNombre++;
        this.awinjard.getAwinjardNameAr().subscribe(res2 => {
          this.drafbiesTab = res2 as Array<Drafbies>
          this.drafbiesTab=this.drafbiesTab.filter((employee)=>employee.DECAFFE==element.AGENT)
          this.nameemployee = this.drafbiesTab[0].AR_DELAFFE;
          console.log(this.drafbiesTab[0].AR_DELAFFE);
          this.nameTable.push(this.nameemployee);
        })
      });
      
      for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
      //those elements that got me the error
        this.employeeL[i].matricule = this.matriculeTable[i];
        this.employeeL[i].fullname = this.nameTable[i];
       
      }

    })
  }
```

the interface

```js
export interface Awinjard {
    matricule: number,
    fullname:string ,
    status: boolean,
    done: number,
    mustBeDone: number,
}
```

Comment: It's probably this line : this.employeeL[i].matricule

Comment: Where are you putting values in the employeeL array?

Comment: the problem is in the ts file in the `for` there I put the data into employeeL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `this.employeeL[i]` is null because you didn't create an empty ith element. All you've done here `employeeL:Array<Awinjard> = [];` is create an array that has no elements.
You should use `push`, this will create a new element on the end of your array that contains your new employee.

Something like this

```
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
     //Create employee(Awinjard) first
     let awin = new Awinjard()
     awin.matricule = this.matriculeTable[i]
     awin.fullname = this.nameTable[i];

     this.employeeL.push(awin)
   
  }
```

Comment: should I change the `Awinjard interface` to class to make the object ??

Comment: You could leave it as an interface and create the object like {matricule:"New matricule", fullname:"New Name"...}. You could also change it to an object and use a contructor with paramaters to create it.

Comment: `let awin=new Awinjard()` this line got me this error `Awinjard' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

Comment: please what you mean by create employee(Awinjard)

Comment: Is Awinjard a class or an interface?

Comment: it is interface , I was add it with the code it is the last one

Comment: new Awinjard() won't work with an interface, only a class

Comment: that's why I ask to make it a class I will change it and test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749030/create-instance-using-an-interface   -  If you decide to keep it as an interface

Comment: thank you friend the error is gone :D , that means a lot to me